# Save stored procedure using command line or any other method

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd, sql-server-2012

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 for my developments. My database has a lot of stored procedures. It is changed some requirements day to day. Sometimes I should have to reverse my development after changing the SP. So what I do is, before changing the SP, I usually get a backup (Right click on SP --> Modify--> and save to my local hard drive location.) This is so headache for me, because every time I should have to do this for getting SP backup.

Is there any method to save SP to local hard drive location? (using command prompt or any other method)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the [sp_helptext](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/25/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-display-code-text-of-stored-procedure-trigger-view-or-object/) with [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) methods. Below outputs the code of stored procedure to text file. See more parameters of the [bcp utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

```
DECLARE @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100), @FilePath NVARCHAR(100) , 
                  @bcpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "execute sp_helptext dbo.sp_name" queryout ' 
SET @FilePath = 'C:\path\to\folder\' 
SET @OutputFile = 'FileName1.txt' 
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername     
exec xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Alternatively, use a programming language (C#, VB, Java, Python, PHP) to connect to your database and execute the `sp_helptext` command and pass results to text file for your backup purposes. And even do so iteratively looping through all stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Look into SQL Server database projects. You simply make the changes in the Visual Studio IDE and then deploy to the target database when you're happy with it. No reverse engineering of source code files required.

Furthermore, you can import an existing database.